# Reading chart data from an Excel file

Tags: python, c#, excel, pandas, charts

I'm trying to find a library (any language, but preferably C# or Python) which will let me open an XLSX file, iterate through the chart objects, and find data about the chart - ideally including the data backing the chart.

The Pandas Python package, or ExcelDataReader NuGet package have useful functionality for opening the file and reading a grid of numbers, as well as ways to add charts, but I don't find any way to read the charts.

Curious to hear from anyone who has ideas/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have a good solution for C#. In C# you can use OLEDB, this allows you to connect a C# code to a excel or access database (so long the database is in the C# code files). You don't need to get any addons for this is you have C# on Visual Studio.